# (Java, EclipseIDE) I am trying to make a button in a Java Swing window

Tags: java, swing, button

I am trying to make buttons for my Java Swing window. With there being 3 labeled buttons and 1 button to add it to the array list (the array list does not have anything to do with this, that can be handled), with them being labeled Class, Time, and Room, where that info is written in the boxes. With the last one being "Enter". Here is my current code for the GUI. I have found all over ways to make a GUI but nowhere can I find how to make boxes where you type in text, or ways to make one in Eclipse.

```
 public void displayGUI()
 {
  //Create and set up the window.
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("iclass");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
  JLabel label = new JLabel(getCurrentClass(), JLabel.CENTER);
  frame.getContentPane().add(label);
  //Display the window.
  JFrame temp = new JFrame();
  temp.pack();
  Insets insets = temp.getInsets();
  //
  frame.setSize(new Dimension(insets.left + insets.right + 320, insets.top + insets.bottom + 320));
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setResizable(true);
  frame.setAlwaysOnTop( false );
 }
```

Comment: You mean a [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)?

Comment: [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) or [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JTextField`.

```
JTextField tf3 = new JTextField("Hello World", 25); // With size and default text
```